# How to install opencv3 on Mac with brew?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I'm using Python 2.7 and was curious how to get opencv3 working on a Mac using brew.

Backstory
This is part of a distributed osX app (py2app) which is why I don't just use a venv. I had opencv2 but was looking into opencv3. I'm also not looking to make the switch to Python 3 since that could impact other libraries or existing source code.
So, I tried

```
brew uninstall opencv    
brew taps homebrew/science
brew install opencv3
brew linkapps opencv3
```

And it works...kind of
Despite not showing any issues, when I attempt to run an app which uses it I get an error showing that cv2 is not found. Any advice on how to fix this? I tried looking up solutions but most people don't appear to be having this same problem. Thanks!